# Python string interpolation using dynamic length strings (using *) with keyword arguments (not `string.format`)

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

For a legacy system that's in use in quite a few places with the string interpolation system I need to implement some code that formats a string with a specific length. I am aware that a `rjust` or `ljust` can solve this, but I'm trying to answer the question whether this is possible with the standard string interpolation system.

Examples:

```
>>> '%0*d' % (5, 3)
'00003'
>>> '%(value)05d' % dict(value=3)
'00003'
```

Now the question is, how can I combine these two?

My failed attempts:

```
>>> '%(value)*d' % dict(value=(5, 3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: * wants int
>>> '%(value)*d' % dict(value=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> '%(value)*d' % {'*': 5, 'value': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> '%(value)*d' % {'*value': 5, 'value': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The question is: how can the asterisk and keyword arguments be combined using string interpolation?

---

**Note:** `str.format` is **not** an answer to this question, I'm not looking for alternatives but simply to answer the question whether this is possible or not. Replacing string interpolation with `str.format` would require many users of the current library to modify the function calls which is a unfavourable option for the near future.

Comment: *"`str.format` is **not** an answer to this question"* - rather than just assert it, could you say *why* not?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I believe I did? That answer would be valid for a different question. The question is not how you can do something similar to this, the question is how this is possible with string interpolation.

Comment: You've surely been around long enough to know how often SO gets XY problems? People ask *"how do I parse HTML with regex"* on a daily basis, and the right answer isn't the one to their direct question! All it takes is *"`str.format` is **not** an answer... because [reasons]"* - is it not supported on the version you're using, for example?

Comment: That's why I was leading with "For a legacy system", I guess that can use some extra clarification. I agree with you that in many cases the question is indeed wrong, I was just trying to indicate that this is indeed the question I wanted to ask.

Comment: *"Replacing string interpolation with str.format would require many users of the current library to modify the function calls"* - does it? That seems odd. Can't you keep the current interface to your function and replace the internal `%` logic with `str.format`? If you need to edit them for the extra options anyway, why not switch to (more modern, more readable - IMO, at least) `str.format` at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) (emphasis mine):

> 4. Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an `'*'` (asterisk), the actual width is read from **the next element of the
>      tuple in *values***, and the object to convert comes after the minimum
>      field width and optional precision.

You need to be passing a tuple, not a dictionary, as values to use the `*` field width. This is then made explicit:

> When the right argument is a dictionary (or other mapping type), ...
>   no `*` specifiers may occur in a format (since they require a sequential
>   parameter list).

Comment: Indeed, it actually just occurred to me to simply look at the source and there is nothing to indicate that this would work any other way. Thanks for the help :)